# Relation between simple pole and radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

**Original problem:** Show that there exists a complex sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that: $\frac{\sin z+1}{\cos z} = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$, for every $z$ in a neighborhood of $0$. Find the radius of convergence of this series.

The solution says that: the function is holomorphic on $D(0,\pi/2)$, its Taylor series converges on this disc. $\pi/2$ is a simple pole, so the radius of convergence is $\pi/2$.

Why is this true?

Comment: How can $\;f\;$ be holomorphic on that disk ( and thus analytic *also* at $\;z=a\;$) and at the same time have a pole at $\;z=a\;$ ?

Comment: Radius of convergence is equal to the shortest distance between the origin and a non-removable singularity.

Comment: I post my original problem. Please have a look.

Comment: @user0896 Thank you. Now Mr has already answered your question.